# Trigger an event when Computer is added to Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

Maybe this is a dumb question, but i'm going to ask i anyway ;)
I need to run a script whenever a Computer is added to my Active Directory.
The easiest way to do this i figured, was to bind a task to an event.
However, i coudn't find any event that gets triggered when a Computer is added to AD, nor did i find a way to active it.

Comment: Do you want to run the task on the client once it's joined, or on the AD server(s) when a client is joined?   What "ways" have you tried already exactly? What's the actual problem you're trying to resolve by running the script like this?

Comment: The script is going to perform an HTTP request, from which the details aren't that relevent. The script can just run on the DC itself. However, i might have found it: when the 'Audit Account Management' Policy is enabled the event 4741 will be triggered when a Computer is created. I think that might do the trick ;)  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: when the 'Audit Account Management' Policy is enabled (explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277403.aspx)) the event 4741 will be triggered when a Computer is created ([source](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4741)). When a task is coupled with this event, you're able to run a script as soon as the event occurs. ;)  Thanks!